# razor page asp-page does not render correct html

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-the-starter-app)

The Index page is in directory: Pages/Contacts
and it has anchor tag as shown below

Create New

This anchor does not render as  href. it is rendered exactly as

```
 <a   asp-page="/Contacts/Create">Create New</a>
```

However if I write the url address Contacts/Create it takes me to the page. Also if write the tag as regular html tag it also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you put

```
<a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Contacts/Index">ContactManager</a>
```

into  `Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` file.

Here is a demo:

Pages structure:

[image]

_Layout.cshtml:

```
...
    <div class="container">
            <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-page="/Contacts/Index">ContactManager</a>
                @RenderBody()
            </main>
        </div>
...
```

Contacts/Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model RazorPageDemo.Pages.Contacts.IndexModel
@{
}
<h1>Contacts/Index page</h1>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: _Layout   has exactly what you suggest:

Comment: I switched to mvc views  which I understand better  than Razor pages